# How can I add search button code where I just want to find record and want to display it in listBoxes

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I am new to C# and I am making a simple database project in which I want to add a functionality in which if user enter the identity number and click the button all the records will be displayed in the list boxes... Please help me to complete it... the code I want to add is in the last section of the code in `button2_click`.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace main_form
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=windowDb;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False");
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        //SqlDataReader dataSearch;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {}

        private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e) {}

        private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(id_Txt.Text!=""& f_txt.Text!=""& Lname_txt.Text!=""& m_txt.Text!=""& dateTimePicker1.Text!=""){
            command.Connection = con;
            con.Open();

            command.CommandText = "insert into people(id,fname,lname,mobile,TDATE) values('"+id_Txt.Text+"','"+f_txt.Text+"','"+Lname_txt.Text+"','"+m_txt.Text+"','"+dateTimePicker1.Text/*Value.ToString()*/+"')";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully");
            id_Txt.Clear();
            f_txt.Clear();
            Lname_txt.Clear();
            m_txt.Clear();
            dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
            search();
            }
        }
        private void search() {

            listBox1.Items.Clear();
            listBox2.Items.Clear();
            listBox3.Items.Clear();
            listBox4.Items.Clear();
            listBox5.Items.Clear();
            con.Open();
            command.CommandText = "select * from people";
            command.Connection = con;

            SqlDataReader dataSearch = command.ExecuteReader();


            if(dataSearch.HasRows){
                while (dataSearch.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(dataSearch["id"].ToString());
                    listBox2.Items.Add(dataSearch["fname"].ToString());
                    listBox3.Items.Add(dataSearch["lname"].ToString());
                    listBox4.Items.Add(dataSearch["mobile"].ToString());
                    listBox5.Items.Add(dataSearch["TDATE"].ToString());
                }
                }

          con.Close();
        }

        private void btn_view_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            search();
        }

        private void bn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (id_Txt.Text != "" & f_txt.Text != "" & Lname_txt.Text != "" & m_txt.Text != "" & dateTimePicker1.Text != "")
            {
                command.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                command.CommandText = "update people  set fname='" + f_txt.Text + "',lname='" + Lname_txt.Text + "',mobile='" + m_txt.Text + "',TDATE='" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "' where id='" +id_Txt.Text + "'";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("Data updated Successfully");
                id_Txt.Clear();
                f_txt.Clear();
                Lname_txt.Clear();
                m_txt.Clear();
                dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
                search();
            }
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox list = sender as ListBox;
            if(list.SelectedIndex!=-1)
            {
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = list.SelectedIndex;
                listBox2.SelectedIndex = list.SelectedIndex;
                listBox3.SelectedIndex = list.SelectedIndex;
                listBox4.SelectedIndex = list.SelectedIndex;
                listBox5.SelectedIndex = list.SelectedIndex;

             //   retrive to TextBox of AllowDrop events;
               /* id_Txt.Text = listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();
                f_txt.Text = listBox2.SelectedIndex.ToString();
                Lname_txt.Text = listBox3.SelectedIndex.ToString();
                m_txt.Text = listBox4.SelectedIndex.ToString();
                dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;*/

                id_Txt.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                f_txt.Text = listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString();
                Lname_txt.Text = listBox3.SelectedItem.ToString();
                m_txt.Text = listBox4.SelectedItem.ToString();
                dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }

        private void btn_delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (id_Txt.Text != "")
            {
                command.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                command.CommandText = "delete from people where id='" + id_Txt.Text + "'";
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("Data deleted Successfully");
                id_Txt.Clear();
                f_txt.Clear();
                Lname_txt.Clear();
                m_txt.Clear();
                dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Now;
                search();
            }

        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {}

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {}

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (text_search.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Enter the Rollno.");
            }
            else {

            }
        }
    }
}
```